# Cockroaches coming from floor drain in bathroom, way to prevent it?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, pest-control

Basically I have Oriental cockroaches coming from the bathroom floor drain. Now the floor drain is not really in use, as in there hasn't been water going in there as there is only a sink that works in that bathroom, but there is also no smell, so I don't think the P trap is empty as I am assuming that smell would've already come years ago.

I am assuming I won't be able to stop these roaches with a domino effect solution, as they keep coming from outside the house, although I will first try a bit of gel around the floor drains, but how should I approach this problem exactly? Is putting a lot of chemicals/insecticides like bleach and cleaning it up a bit first or as second (after gel baits) a good idea, and then buy a drain catcher and close it off like that then once in a while I will pour in water to maintain.

Let me know, and let me know how these guys came up from there if there was water in the p-trap.

Comment: Is there any grate or the like on top? That should be stopping all but the smallest bugs from getting through.

Comment: Just because you do not smell anything is no reason to assume that the trap is full. Try filling it and then you will not have to assume.

Comment: Roaches may not be entering the home through the pipe but they will gag out in there because they have a water source.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I also want to pour down some chemical, what would you recommend?